# Artifactory FileSystemUsage much bigger than TotalRepositorySize

Tags: artifactory

JFrog Artifactory, really a cool thing - i'm runing out of space, so i followed the docs at:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Regular+Maintenance+Operations#RegularMaintenanceOperations-CleanupUnusedCachedArtifacts

a question arrises: 
Storage Summary shows use of **60GB**, but Total Repository Artifacts Size is **12GB**.
i checked the backup's folder, but the main-part is in /filestore ( about 55GB ) which is some kind of binary store ....

is this normal ?

Comment: There's a similar problem with cleaning up from Artifactory v6.12+, see: https://serverfault.com/questions/1031859

Answer (score 1):

Yes, artifactory stores the data at the backend based on checksum. The metadata of the artifacts are stored in the db -- which is defined in the db.properties file. The UI displays the metadata from the DB and the artifacts are referred from the checksum storage in the backend server.

filestore is where the artifacts are stored.

There is a plugin in artifactory where the artifacts can be deleted using groovy based on the artifacts date.

I have also return a python script that will delete the artifacts after calculating 3 months from the latest build

Comment: ok, thank you for making it clear.... I saw the groovy scripts, but I run community-version.... and the API denies with 400 - check for pro license.... may you share you python script?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/ybagarka1/artifactory/blob/master/artifactory_retention.py. Please let me know in case any issues. The script using aql I am not sure but think so you won't be able to run on open source but please try. Also jfrog cli can be used for opensource in case the above doesn't works